# Atalho para renomear, sobrepor ou substituir palavras ou variaveis iguais no Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text

No Eclipse, existe uma funcionalidade que é acionada pelos comandos `CTRL + ALT + U` (Me corrijam se eu estiver errado) que renomeia variáveis com o mesmo nome.
Vocês conhecem algum atalho do *Sublime Text 3* que faça isso? Ou é algum plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Alt + F3` seleciona todas as palavras iguais de uma única vez.

`Ctrl + D` incrementa a seleção para o mais próximo (seguinte e não o anterior), caso não queira alterar todas.

Comment: Muito bom o `alt+f3`. Eu ficava apertando o `CTRL+D` infinitamente, até chegar ao máximo

Answer (score 3):

`CTRL + D` seleciona um por um do mesmo nome. Apertando várias vezes, ele vai selecionando um por um com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

No primeiro campo o objeto que procura, no segundo campo onde é o arquivo que deseja modificar, terceiro e último o conteúdo que deseja substituir.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço assim: Seleciono o texto ao qual quero mudar todas as variáveis/componentes e pressiono <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> então eu seleciono o que quero mudar, o Delphi seleciona todas as variáveis com o mesmo nome no trecho que eu selecionei e muda simultaneamente. Depois que terminei de editar, pressiono <kbd>Esc</kbd> para fechar/concluir.

Answer (score -1):

Aperte <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> e siga os passos abaixo:

1. Digite o nome da variável que quer trocar no primeiro campo.
2. No segundo campo digita o novo nome;
3. Clique em replace all e todas as variáveis serão atualizadas.