# Sublime, sobrepor/substituir códigos

Tags: sublime-text-2

Olá, estou querendo substituir todos os caracteres que tem a cor #a10f2b no Sublime Text 2.

Eu sei que é possível, mas não consegui encontrar a resposta.

Quero substituir todas as cores do tema CSS.

Comment: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace.html

Comment: Olá? Pode responder a pergunta?

Comment: Conseguiu  substituir ? antes de  fazer perguntas tente pesquisar sobre a dúvida para ver se já existe alguma resposta no stackoverflow ou no goolge.

Comment: Para de ser bobo, no google tem praticamente tudo, mas na comunidade  do Stack Overflow em português não achei nada. Esta pergunta pode ajudar muita gente.

O link que você passou não responde a pergunta e também não está em português. Você nem leu o que mandou.

Comment: Concordo com o @FelipeJorge. Achamos tudo no Google, mas se acharmos em português (aqui então) é sempre melhor!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67509/atalho-para-renomear-palavras-ou-variaveis-iguais-no-sublime-text-3

Comment: Troquei o título do outro post para evitar duplicatas futuras e facilitar a busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for em um arquivo só, você pode usar o atalho `CTRL+D`, depois de ter selecionado a cor. Daí, você vai apertando até que seja selecionado todas. Isso fará que, quando você digitar, todas as ocorrências de `#a10f2b` sejam substituidas em "tempo real"

[image: Exemplo CTRL+D]

Se estiver querendo fazer isso no projeto inteiro, poderá fazer isso através do `CTRL+SHIFT+F`.

Daí é só preencher o campo a procurar em `find`, o valor da substituição em `replace`, o valor da pasta a procurar em `where`, e clicar em `replace`. Depois é só ir em `File > Save all`

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]